# compare list with a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, function, nested

I need a function that compares two lists and pulls values from 1st.
I have one list.

```
shopping_list = [['1', 'shirt', '8.99'], ['2', 'pants', '10.99'], ['3', 'socks', '5.99'], ['4', 'hat', '9.99'], ['5', 'shoes', '14.99']]
```

I have a final list

```
cart = ['shirt', 'pants', 'shirt']
```

I need to know how to pull the values of the items in the second list from the first list and add them together.
(8.99 + 10.99 + 8.99 = 28.97)

```
def subtotal(shopping_list, cart):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(shopping_list)):
        if shopping_list[i][0] == i:
            item_name = shopping_list[i][1]
            for j in cart:
                if j == item_name:
                    total += int(shopping_list[i][2])
            print('Your subtotal is ', total)
    return total
```

gets me absolutely nothing

Comment: Please note that `cart = burrito, stir fry,  burrito` makes `cart` a _tuple_, not a list. Also don't forget the quotes around strings. Finally, see [formatting help](/help/formatting). Code blocks are created by typing three backticks (`\`\`\``) on the lines before and after your code.

Comment: What is `if menu_list[i][0] == i:` supposed to be checking for?

Comment: You should also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and learn how to use a debugger to step through your program to inspect its operation line-by-line to catch any issues.

Comment: In your case `if menu_list[i][0] == i` will *never* evaluate to `True`.  Because, for example, `1 != '1'`.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a list for the menu? A dictionary is a better data structure to use here

Comment: this is a single function in a larger program that uses menu_list as a list.

Comment: i am very new to python and can use all the help possible

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues with your code, so I'm going to suggest a different approach: For your menu, use a dictionary instead of a list. A dictionary allows you to look up values (in this case prices) by the key (name of the item) without having to loop over the entire dictionary to find it. You can convert the `menu_list` to a dictionary once, and then keep using that:

```
from decimal import Decimal
menu_dict = {item[1]: Decimal(item[2]) for item in menu_list}
```

This loops over each `item` in `menu_list`. Each `item` itself is a list containing three strings: an index, the item name, and the item's price. The dictionary comprehension creates a dictionary whose keys are the second element of `item` (i.e. its name, `item[1]`) and whose values are the third element of `item` (i.e. its price, converted to a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html): `Decimal(item[2])`). You could also use `float` instead of `Decimal`, but see note 3 below for why you shouldn't.

This results in the following dictionary given your `menu_list`:

```
{
 'burrito': Decimal('6.99'),
 'stir fry': Decimal('7.99'),
 'hamburger': Decimal('8.99'),
 'cheeseburger': Decimal('9.99'),
 'french fries': Decimal('4.99')
}
```

Next, let's revamp your `subtotal` function:

```
def subtotal(menu, cart): 
    total = 0
    for item_name in cart:
        try:
            total += menu[item_name]
        except KeyError:
            print(f"Sorry, we don't sell {item_name}")

    return total
```

Here, `subtotal` expects the menu *dictionary* and the cart list.
This function loops over each `item_name` in the `cart` list, and tries to look up its value in the `menu` dictionary. If it finds `item_name` in the dictionary, the price is added to `total`. If not, a `KeyError` is raised by python. This `KeyError` is then caught by the `except KeyError` clause, and a nice message is printed, and nothing is added for that item to the `total`.

Note: If you didn't want to print a message, and instead silently add nothing, you could replace the entire `try..except` block with simply `total += menu.get(item_name, 0)`. The `.get` method of a dictionary tries to return the key given by the first argument, and if it fails, returns the supplied second argument instead.

```
cart = ['burrito', 'stir fry', 'burrito', 'tiramisu']

cart_subtotal = subtotal(menu_dict, cart)
```

Now, `cart_subtotal` is the expected value, `21.97`, and a message was printed indicating that tiramisu is not on the menu.

---

Maybe it'll help you learn if I point out the problems with your code line-by-line.

Before we even get into coding, you need to think about whether the approach you are using has any unnecessary inefficiencies. For example, when looking for an item in a list, you need to traverse (possibly) the entire list. This is a slow operation in python, but has the potential to significantly slow your code down if you do this many times. In your approach, you loop over every item in `menu_list` and then try to find that item in the cart by looping over the cart itself. If both `menu_list` and `cart` were sufficiently large, your code would slow down to a crawl. The alternative here is to use a dictionary, as I do. A dictionary offers fast lookup of values based on keys, so you don't need to traverse the entire list looking for each item.

Now, let's start with your function:

```
def subtotal(menu_list, cart):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(menu_list)):
        if menu_list[i][0] == i:
            item_name = menu_list[i][1]
            for j in cart:
                if j == item_name:
                    total += int(menu_list[i][2])
            print('Your subtotal is ', total)
    return total
```

1. The line `for i in range(len(menu_list))`:  In python, we loop over the *items* in a list (`for item in my_list`) instead of looping over the indices of the list (`for index in range(len(my_list))`) and then accessing elements using that index (`item = my_list[index]`).
2. The line `if menu_list[i][0] == i`: `menu_list[i][0]` is always a string. `i` is an integer. These two things will never be equal. What's more, the values of `menu_list[i][0]` start at 1, but `range` starts at zero, so even if strings could equal integers, this condition would never be true. Since this condition is never true, the rest of your function is never executed. What is the purpose of this check anyway?
3. If we ignore the problem above, you loop over `cart` to find `item_name` (you do this loop the correct (*pythonic*) way). When you find an item in the cart of the same name, you convert the price in the menu to an `int`, but these prices are *not* integers, they contain decimals. You should instead convert these to `float` or [`Decimal`]s (see [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/843953) for why `Decimal` is preferred)

Comment: Perhaps `total += menu[item_name]` can be changed to `total += menu.get(item_name, 0)` to prevent the `KeyError`.  Just a thought.

Comment: @S3DEV True, but I went the `try..except` route to illustrate what happens when a key doesn't exist, and how to print a message instead of silently adding nothing to the total. I added a note to this effect in the answer.

Comment: all of this was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

In this case it's more convenient to use dictionaries instead of arrays. This way searches can be executed more quickly using the key of each item to obtain its price.

```
menu_list = {
    "burrito": 6.99,
    "stir fry": 7.99,
    "hamburger": 8.99
}

cart = ['burrito', 'stir fry', 'burrito']

total = 0
for elements in cart:
    total += menu_list[elements]

print(total)
# 21.97
# 
# Process finished with exit code 0
```